# How can I find the correct reference in the webconfig for System.Web.Extensions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm having error when I run my 3.5 web app from Visual Studio 2005 (yeah I know..)

[image: Error Message]

I had removed and added again the this conflicted project reference in order to work. How can I find the correct reference in the web.config for this System.Web.Extensions?

Comment: is it because of ajax extension? can you install ajax extension on that machine?

Comment: what version is referenced in your project, under references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArsenMkrt, it worked after installing the ajax extension, put it as an answer so I can mark it, thanks